# Groovy Meta Programming: Override Map invokeMethod

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I have a java `Map<String,Object>` that i'm accessing using groovy's magical

```
myMap.property1.nestedProperty1.nestedNestedProperty
```

This is great and I know I can safe navigate like this:

```
myMap?.property1?.nestedProperty1?.nestedNestedProperty
```

But, when I'm traversing a huge hierarchical nested map, remembering to always safe navigating can get tedious.

I think groovy implements the nest graph navigation by using the `invokeMethod` override.

What is the recommended/best way for me to modify that behaviour to safe navigate by default without me having to do `?.` everytime?

I intend to override only my map objects `metaClass.invokeMethod` and not the Class one.

PS: I've been searching the groovy source code in vain. Can someone also point to where exactly groovy implements this functionality on the Java Map implementations?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might try is using ConfigObject, which already has this "safety".

```
ConfigObject conf = myMap as ConfigObject
```

Now you can do `conf.property1.nestedProperty1.nestedNestedProperty` and it will always resolve, even if any level is missing in the original map.

However, the result when you're done, if any piece is missing, isn't `null`, it's a ConfigObject where `isEmpty()` is true.   You can just test this using `instanceof` if you like, so:

```
myMap?.property1?.nestedProperty1?.nestedNestedProperty
```

is equivalent to:

```
ConfigObject conf = myMap as ConfigObject
Object value = conf.property1.nestedProperty1.nestedNestedProperty
value = (value instanceof ConfigObject ) ? null: value
```

You could very easily write a method that performs the above more cleanly.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.9/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigObject.html

Comment: This is very interesting, but now, I feel like I've gone from expecting people to remember to use safe navigation to expecting people to do this check in the end, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is, you can't call a method on a null, and you're saying you want intermediate failures to return null, since you can't *tell* it's an intermediate failure.  Those requirements conflict.

Comment: I think I see that problem. I was seeing `?.` as a single operator being called on the null object and I wanted to figure out how to turn `.` into `?.`, but I suppose you calling `?` on `null` in this case and returning immediately if the delegate is infact `null`.